# Is it possible to set a BLOB size when creating table?

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I am new to Oracle sql, but I have some experience with MSSQL. I was sent a script to create some tables, but because of the BLOB columns, I am getting a couple errors when I try to limit the size.

I tried asking my co-workers about this, but they aren't sure either. This was basically grabbed from somewhere else, so they're not sure how to fix this.

Essentially, the table looks something like this (table and column names were changed):

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    ID       CHAR(32),
    NAME     CHAR(50),
    KEY      $(BLOB)(64),
    BUFFER   $(BLOB)(20),
    SORTNO   NUMERIC(8) CONSTRAINT UK_WIU UNIQUE,
CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
;
```

When running this, I get the error "invalid character" because of the dollar sign ($). But if I change data type to BLOB(64), I get an error saying "missing right parenthesis." If I just do "BLOB," it runs fine. Is there any way to define the length for BLOB?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BLOB` column's size can't be restricted. It allows you to store up to [(4 gigabytes - 1) * (database block size)] data, and that's it. If you need less than that, fine, no problem.

More about BLOB (and other Oracle 18c datatypes) here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-1A71C635-188E-4EC9-B821-1DBEC2B45451

Table you meant to create would in Oracle look like this:

```
SQL> create table table1
  2    (id     varchar2(32) constraint pk_id primary key,
  3     name   varchar2(50),
  4     sortno number(8) constraint uk_wiu unique,
  5     key    blob,
  6     buffer blob
  7    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Yet another objection regarding your code: don't use `CHAR` but `VARCHAR2` (unless you have to); `CHAR` will right-pad values with spaces, up to the maximum length of the column.

Comment: Thank you, I'll just use BLOB then. I'm not sure where they are getting they were getting the length from. Good tip on using VARCHAR2. I'll have to get that OK'd to be able to change it too, but I don't see any reason not to use it for our data.

Answer (score 0):

No, columns are just defined as a CLOB or BLOB.

There is no size associated with the column. You can put in something as big or small as you like, with a few [restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903).

"Maximum size: (4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE initialization parameter (8 TB to 128 TB)"..as of 11g of Oracle.

To limit the size, you could, do so at the application layer - prevent folks from uploading files larger than X, although someone with DB access could do this.

You could write a stored procedure for handling INSERT/UPDATES, and have logic in there to prevent DML if the size is 'too large.'

You might be able to do a check constraint using a function call to get the length of the lob...an example [here](https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Setting-maximum-size-of-a-blob-data-type,8)